# How to handle encoding when sending Marshaled data over a pipe from a forked process?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get data back from a forked child process to the master process like this:

```rb
read, write = IO.pipe

pid = fork do

  # Generate some data in the child process

  Marshal.dump(generated_data, write)
  exit!(0)
end

Process.wait(pid)
write.close
data = Marshal.load(read.read)
read.close
```

This works perfectly for my initial test cases, however when the data generated within the child process gets more complicated, I start running into encoding errors like this when calling `Marshal.dump(generated_data, write)`:

```
*** Encoding::UndefinedConversionError Exception: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

I guess this is because the pipe is setup to handle UTF-8 data instead of ASCII-8BIT as being generated by Marshal, but so far I have been enable to work out how to configure the pipe correctly.

e.g. This doesn't fix it:

```
read,write = IO.pipe('ASCII-8BIT')
```

Comment: Have you tried `pipe('BINARY:BINARY')`?

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but I just did and it makes no difference. It's as if passing the encoding to the `pipe` method doesn't do anything, I get exactly the same error message as above. Thanks though.

Comment: Are you sure that exception is being generated by the pipe you've created and not some other filehandle?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure. I did have to actually change the code slightly to see the error as originally the code as written in the question was swallowing it and Marshal.dump was just hanging. I now have `str = Marshal.dump(generated_data); write.write(str)  # => Encoding error`

Comment: It's worth verifying that the `external_encoding` and `internal_encoding` of that pipe are set correctly because it sounds like something's gone awry.

Comment: Thanks for your help man. It turns out that it wasn't actually related to the encoding, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this problem only occurred on data strings longer than a certain length, in my case 64KB, and this corresponds to the size of the IO pipe buffer - which as far as I can tell is governed by the sytem you are running on and you cannot change it.

I suspect that this encoding error occurs because the string gets chopped at a non-natural boundary at somewhere in the process.

Changing my code to read a defined number of bytes fixed the problem:

```
reader, writer = IO.pipe
reader.binmode
writer.binmode

pid = fork do

  # Generate some data in the child process

  str = Marshal.dump(generated_data)
  writer.puts(str.bytesize)
  writer.write(str)
  writer.close
  exit!(0)
end

# Get the size of the return string, this will block until the fork has the data ready 
size_in_bytes = reader.gets.strip.to_i
str = reader.read(size_in_bytes)
reader.close

return_data = Marshal.load(str)
```

*EDIT: Actually putting the pipe into binary mode is important too, the above solution is now robust in my application for transferring significant amounts of Marshaled data between the child and parent processes*

Comment: It could be that flooding the pipe causes lost data. Where that's an issue you may need to use [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-select) to check if the pipe is ready to write before jamming data into it.